# Lambda function operations using groupby.apply() in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, lambda

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

The code to build it is:

```
data = {'Position Date': ['2022-01-02',  '2022-01-02',  '2022-01-02',  '2022-01-02',  '2022-01-03',  '2022-01-03',  '2022-01-03',  '2022-01-03'],
 'Client': ['Client 1',  'Client 1',  'Client 2',  'Client 2',  'Client 1',  'Client 1',  'Client 2',  'Client 2'],
 'Product': ['Product 1',  'Product 4',  'Product 2',  'Product 3',  Product 1',  'Product 4',  'Product 2',  'Product 3'],
 'Buy Date': ['2022-05-02',  '2022-06-02',  '2022-03-12',  '2022-01-25',  '2022-05-02',  '2022-06-02',  '2022-03-12',  '2022-01-25'],
 'Position': [130, 5000, 120, 77, 150, 7000, 200, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['Position Date', 'Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date'])

df['PL'] = df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date']).diff().fillna(0)
```

So, now I need to create a new column X that divides a the "current day" PL (index 0) by the last day Position (with index -1).

For example: on the day 2022-01-03, Client 1, product 1 the x would be:

X = PL[index 0] / Position[-1] = 20/ 130

The expected output would be:

[image]

As the first day's values are 0 and the others are:
20/130,  2000/5000,  80/120,  23/77

I was trying something like

```
df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date']).apply(lambda x: x['PL'] / x['Position'].iloc[-1])
```

But I keep getting errors.

Comment: So the 100 in the denominator is not a Client1/Product1? Maybe make your numbers unique for clarity and provide the full expected output

Comment: Yes it is, the goal is to take the same client/product/buy date's PL and divide it by the last Position Date's Position

Comment: @mozway Edited values for better comprehension.

Comment: @mozway and added the full expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use indexing here:

```
df['output'] = df['PL'].div(df.loc[df.index[0][0], 'Position']
                              .reindex(df.droplevel('Position Date').index).values
                           )
```

Output:

```
                                             Position      PL    output
Position Date Client   Product   Buy Date                              
2022-01-02    Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02       130     0.0  0.000000
                       Product 4 2022-06-02      5000     0.0  0.000000
              Client 2 Product 2 2022-03-12       120     0.0  0.000000
                       Product 3 2022-01-25        77     0.0  0.000000
2022-01-03    Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02       150    20.0  0.153846
                       Product 4 2022-06-02      7000  2000.0  0.400000
              Client 2 Product 2 2022-03-12       200    80.0  0.666667
                       Product 3 2022-01-25       100    23.0  0.298701
```

Intermediates:

```
df.loc[df.index[0][0], 'Position']

Client    Product    Buy Date  
Client 1  Product 1  2022-05-02     130
          Product 4  2022-06-02    5000
Client 2  Product 2  2022-03-12     120
          Product 3  2022-01-25      77
Name: Position, dtype: int64

(df.loc[df.index[0][0], 'Position']
   .reindex(df.droplevel('Position Date').index)
)

Client    Product    Buy Date  
Client 1  Product 1  2022-05-02     130
          Product 4  2022-06-02    5000
Client 2  Product 2  2022-03-12     120
          Product 3  2022-01-25      77
Client 1  Product 1  2022-05-02     130
          Product 4  2022-06-02    5000
Client 2  Product 2  2022-03-12     120
          Product 3  2022-01-25      77
Name: Position, dtype: int64

(df.loc[df.index[0][0], 'Position']
   .reindex(df.droplevel('Position Date').index)
   .values
)

array([ 130, 5000,  120,   77,  130, 5000,  120,   77])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it really worked. I don't fully comprehend what's going on there but it got the result.

Comment: @João it's slicing just the first Position Date with `df.loc[df.index[0][0], 'Position']`, and reindexes it to have the same shape as the full DataFrame, then converts to array to avoid issues with the MultiIndex. I suggest you try to see the output of the individual parts in my edit and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I tested it in this example dataframe and it worked just fine. But as I went to test out on the real dataframe some errors occurred. On some dates I don't have the Values for a Client, for example: on the day 2023-01-03 it might not have the  "Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02      150   20" . So in this case the shapes of the dataframe for each date will be slightly different. Any ideia on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```py
df["X"] = df["PL"].div(df["Position"].shift(4)).fillna(0.0).values
```

where **4** in the `shift` method is the total number of products (Product 1, Product 2, Product 3 and Product 4) in a day in the `Position Date` column