# Applying division between values in the same groupby but with different indexes on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, indexing

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

The code to build it is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Client'] = ['Client 1', 'Client 1','Client 2','Client 2', 'Client 1', 'Client 2','Client 2']
df['Product'] = ['Product 1', 'Product 4', 'Product 2', 'Product 3',  'Product 4', 'Product 2', 'Product 3']
df['Position Date'] = ['2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-03']
df['Buy Date'] = ['2022-05-02', '2022-06-02', '2022-03-12', '2022-01-25', '2022-06-02', '2022-03-12', '2022-01-25']
df['Position'] = [130, 5000, 120, 77,  7000, 200, 100]
df['PL'] = [0,0,0,0, 50, 2000, 80, 100]

df = df.set_index(['Position Date','Client',  'Product', 'Buy Date'], drop=True)

df['PL'] = df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date']).diff().fillna(0)
```

So, now I need to create a new column X that divides a the "current day" PL (index 0) by the last day Position (with index -1).

For example: on the day 2022-01-03, Client 2, product 2 the x would be:

X = PL[index 0] / Position[-1] = 80 / 120

The expected output would be:

[image]

As the first day's values are 0 and the others are: 2000/5000,  80/120,  23/77

I have asked a similar question [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146785/lambda-function-operations-using-groupby-apply-in-dataframe), and @mozway kindly solved it for me using a reindex solution:

```
df['output'] = df['PL'].div(df.loc[df.index[0][0], 'Position']
                          .reindex(df.droplevel('Position Date').index).values
                       )
```

But I forgot a crucial point in this test database, for some Position Dates we don't have the same information about the positions. For example, the group 2022-01-03 / Client 1 doesn't have the same shape as the group 2022-01-02 / Client 1. The question would be how to apply the division regardless the shape of each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby` then apply your function:

```
>>> (df.groupby(level=['Client', 'Product', 'Buy Date'], as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda x: x['PL'] / x['Position'].shift())
       .fillna(0).to_frame('X').droplevel(0)).sort_index()

                                                    X
Position Date Client   Product   Buy Date            
2022-01-02    Client 1 Product 1 2022-05-02  0.000000
                       Product 4 2022-06-02  0.000000
              Client 2 Product 2 2022-03-12  0.000000
                       Product 3 2022-01-25  0.000000
2022-01-03    Client 1 Product 4 2022-06-02  0.400000
              Client 2 Product 2 2022-03-12  0.666667
                       Product 3 2022-01-25  0.298701
```